# click event not triggered on nodes and connections of a jsplumb graph on mobile

Tags: angular, mobile, jsplumb

I have an Angular app with a jsPlumb graph built dynamically from data in a database, and on each node and connection created, the user can click to edit properties and save them to database.

I test with Google Chrome and everything works fine in desktop mode, but when I switch to smartphone mode using Chrome dev tools, nothing is triggered when I click on a node or a connection.

For connections I solved the issue. I am using dashed connections, and these connections trigger the click or tap event only when you click on the dashes, not if you click between the dashes. It may be hard to click in the exact place on smartphones, so I doubled every connection with a "fake" connection with no dashes, and now I can click anywhere and it works.

However I have still the problem with the click on nodes, and more specifically the click on icon in nodes.

Here is the HTML code:

```
                <div #learningPlanGraphNode
                    *ngFor="let learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode of learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNodes"
                    [ngClass]="{
                            'window-not-clickable': true
                        }" id="{{'courseWindow' + learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.stepId}}"
                    [style.top]="learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.top + 'em'"
                    [style.left]="learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.left + 'em'"
                    [style.borderColor]="learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.color">
                    <!-- subscription not required -->
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.subscriptionRequired === 0"
                        class="kps-node-top-left-icon-na"
                        (click)="editCourseUserSubscription(learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.stepId)">face
                    </mat-icon>
                    <!-- subscription required but no subscription -->
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.subscriptionRequired !== 0 
                        && learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.subscriptionId === 0" class="kps-node-top-left-icon-ko"
                        (click)="editCourseUserSubscription(learningPlanWithUserAccessRightsGraphNode.stepId)">face
                    </mat-icon>
```

and the code goes on with other icons, each icon being displayed for a specific condition.

Here is the CSS code for those icons:

```
[id^=courseWindow] mat-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 21;
}
[id^=courseWindow] mat-icon:hover {
    color: #FF9201 !important;
}
.kps-node-top-left-icon-na{
  color: #8E1E07 !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And so on for other icons.

Click event works on Chrome in desktop mode, also in Chrome in smartphone mode using dev tools, but it does not work on native Android Chrome.

Comment: Can you share some codes to recreate your problem?

Comment: I have updated my question since I fixed the issue for connections but not for icons in nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I used Chrome dev tools to track which events where fired when clicking on nodes.

And the truth is you need to use the pointerup event instead of the click event to make it work both on desktop and mobile.